# Running GWT + App Engine in non-development mode

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm using Google plug-in for Eclipse and it seems like there's only dev mode available. How can I run my GWT application on App Engine locally in native (non-development) mode, so I can test in browsers that don't have GWT plug-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Compile your GWT project. This should produce JS and html files in the WEB-INF folder.
2. Create an App Engine run configuration an run it.

Comment: I figured it out that development mode runs on top of regular one. Development mode link looks like http://127.0.0.1:8888/Test.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 and by default GAE runs at http://localhost:8888/. So yeah, you just compile it and run as GWT web application.

Answer (score 0):

GWT Compile your project.  Go to your war directory of your project. Open the index.html file with your browser of choice.  I believe this should work.

Comment: This will run GWT code, but it won't be deployed on App Engine.I need a way to deploy the code on App Engine locally without running code in dev mode.